# Convert JSON into string for MQTT

Tags: string, mqtt, c-string

I am trying to publish json object into string with following snippet

```
JSONVar data;
data["chipid"] = chipId;
data["co2_equivalent"] = co2_equivalent.c_str();
data["tvoc"] = tvoc.c_str();
data["h2_signal"] = h2_signal;
data["ethanol_signal"] = ethanol_signal;
data["humidity"] = humidity;
data["temperature"] = temperature;
data["absolute_hum"] = v.absolute_hum;
data["co2_equivalent_baseline"] = co2_equivalent_baseline;
data["tvoc_baseline"] = tvoc_baseline;

String data_json = JSON.stringify(data);
Serial.print(data_json);
Serial.println();
client.publish("/devices/data", data_json);
```

This give me following error during compilation.

```
  /Users/ubuntu/Desktop/Arduino/data_collection/esp32-svm30-mqtt.ino/esp32-svm30-mqtt.ino.ino: In function 'void loop()':
  esp32-svm30-mqtt.ino:271:46: error: no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::publish(const char [14], String&)'
       client.publish("/devices/data", data_json);
                                                ^
  In file included from /Users/ubuntu/Desktop/Arduino/data_collection/esp32-svm30-mqtt.ino/esp32-svm30-mqtt.ino.ino:2:0:
  /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:141:12: note: candidate: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const char*)
      boolean publish(const char* topic, const char* payload);
              ^
  /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:141:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'String' to 'const char*'
  /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:142:12: note: candidate: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const char*, boolean)
      boolean publish(const char* topic, const char* payload, boolean retained);
              ^
  /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:142:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
  /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:143:12: note: candidate: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int)
      boolean publish(const char* topic, const uint8_t * payload, unsigned int plength);
              ^
  /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:143:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
  /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:144:12: note: candidate: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int, boolean)
      boolean publish(const char* topic, const uint8_t * payload, unsigned int plength, boolean retained);
              ^
  /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:144:12: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
  Multiple libraries were found for "PubSubClient.h"
   Used: /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient
  Multiple libraries were found for "Arduino_JSON.h"
   Used: /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Arduino_JSON
  Multiple libraries were found for "svm30.h"
   Used: /Users/ubuntu/Documents/Arduino/libraries/svm30
  Multiple libraries were found for "Wire.h"
   Used: /Users/ubuntu/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.4/libraries/Wire
  Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
   Used: /Users/ubuntu/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.4/libraries/WiFi
   Not used: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/WiFi
  exit status 1
  no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::publish(const char [14], String&)'
```

Line `Serial.print(data_json)` does print it in serial monitor.

Update :

If I do`client.publish("/devices/data", data_json.c_str());`, it gets compiled, but data doesn't appear in mqtt.

`Serial.print(data_json.length());` prints **236**

Is my json to string conversion correct ?

Answer (score 1):

> Please note: the question originally had no mention of trying to use `c_str()` - so I'm not a retard

Point 1 JSON actually is a string
Point 2 your `data_json` varibale is a `String`
Point 3 `client.publish` doesn't work take `String` as the *payload* argument, it takes either `const char *` or `const uint8_t *`

So, what you can simply do is use `String`s `c_str` method to pas a `const char *` as the payload

i.e.

```
client.publish("/devices/data", data_json.c_str());
```

Point 4 - if you read the pubsubclient documentation, you'll see that

> The maximum message size, including header, is 128 bytes by default. This is configurable via MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE in PubSubClient.h. Longer messages can also be sent with the publish_P() method.

so what you may be experiencing now is a message size too big for pubsubclient to handle - set a larger packet size before including the PubSubClientHeader.h

```
#define MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE 1024
#include <pubsubclient.h>
```

If that also doesn't work, try

```
client.publish_P("/devices/data", data_json.c_str());
```

Comment: I tried `data_json.c_str()` but still data doesn't appear in mqtt.

Comment: @roy - but it compiles now?

Comment: Yes its getting compiled, but data not getting to mqtt.

Comment: @roy - updated the answer with another possible problem - which you have confirmed with your latest update that the payload is over 128 length ... meaning the whole message is WELL over 128

Comment: I tried adding `#define MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE 1024`, still no data appearing in mqtt.

Comment: @roy - what if you set a fixed payload? I can't recall if you tried that since you keep editing the question - you did add that define BEFORE you included the header file?

Comment: If i just publish fixed data it works like this `client.publish("/devices/data", "1234567890");`

Comment: and now that you've increased the packet size, it still doesn't work? it's odd, because if `Serial.print(data_json);` prints a string, and the string is far less than 1024, this should've worked - can you `Serial.print(MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE);` just to be sure

Comment: try using `client.publish_P("/devices/data", data_json.c_str());`

Comment: You have almost tried everything and @Jaromanda has given an answer that should possibly work. Can you please try the following things `const char *buffer = NULL; //declaring const char * buffer = strdup(data_json.c_str()); //duplicating the string client.publish("/devices/data", buffer); //publish it MQTT`